# Sending custom email template in phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

How can i send a new Transactional Email with order information in the success.phtml? And how can i add custom order information?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @AmitBera i have create a new Tranactional Email in the adminpanel but cannot find the template in my files and don't know how i can send the email in the success page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. I use this code to send the email in the phtml file

```
 $templateId = 2;
 $sendername = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
 $senderemail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
 $sender = Array('name' => $sendername,
 'email' => $senderemail);
 //recepient

 $email = $email;
 $emailName = $name;
 $vars = Array();
 $vars = Array('tickets'=>$alle_tickets,'order_id'=>$order_id);
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
 $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
 Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
 ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $emailName, $vars, $storeId);
 $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```